# Android editTextValue duplicate in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I still unsolved problem.

There are editText in ListView and TextView. When scrolling the ListView editText duplicate values ​​are output.

Found to cause getView () problem in the ListView will recycle the item has been found

Stack overflow and headaches in a person like me, I tried to post.

I just like to see and respond

However, this does not solve the problem.

In addition, in response inflater.inflate (R.layout.listview_item, parent, null) method was non-existent

Detailed answer about this problem, please help me to ask

Thank you.

-My Android source-

public class ListViewAdpter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Context context;
ArrayList<ListItemVO> itemList;
List<String> editList;


static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public EditText editText;
}


public ListViewAdpter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItemVO> arr) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemList = arr;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return itemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return itemList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView111);

        viewHolder.editText = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.editText111);

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    holder.text.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());


    return rowView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where your `if` statement ends, put an `else` statement and inside that write

```
viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
```

also declare variable of ViewHolder class outside of `if-else`, like this

```
View rowView = convertView;
ViewHolder viewHolder;

if (convertView == null) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView111);

    viewHolder.editText = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.editText111);

    rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

}else{
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
}

holder.text.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());


return rowView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `holder.editText.setText("");` to your `getView()` method. Or any text you need.

Because `convertView` copies previous view with all parameters including texts, colors, etc..